# WooCommerce Add Extra Tabs - Single Product Page

Tags: tabs, woocommerce

The following is the code from WooCommerce to Add Extra Tabs:
My Question is, how to insert a video link, or an iframe in the tab content.

---

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woo_new_product_tab' );
function woo_new_product_tab( $tabs ) {

    // Adds the new tab

    $tabs['test_tab'] = array(
        'title'     => __( 'New Product Tab', 'woocommerce' ),
        'priority'  => 50,
        'callback'  => 'woo_new_product_tab_content'
    );

    return $tabs;

}
function woo_new_product_tab_content() {

    // The new tab content

    echo '<h2>New Product Tab</h2>';
    echo '<p>Here\'s your tab content.</p>';

}
```

---

How to insert anchor text, or iframe inside "Tab Content"

Any Help would appreciated..

Cheers

Comment: I have managed to get the text,, but not able to insert a You tube URL:

Comment: echo "We will soon update the video here"; Instead I want to show an iframe..

Comment: Done,, Thanks Guys,,

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to show a static video iframe in your tab content, then simply add iframe/video tag in your tab content callback function likes

```
function woo_new_product_tab_content() {
  // The new tab content
  echo '<h2>See the video</h2>';
  echo '<div><iframe width="100%" height="315" src="paste your video link here" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>'; }
```

Or if your wants dynamic video link for each product then you must have to store video link in respective product meta first. And then echo get_post_meta for video on above 'src' attr.